# Resttemplate is giving 400 Bad Request error after working for sometime

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I've a `RestTemplate` that is sending get requests to a URL to get some data of type `String`. The code is working fine for sometime. But all of a sudden all the requests for the same URL are failing with `400: Bad Request error`.

```
try {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = this.rest.getForEntity(uri, String.class);
    body = response.getBody();
} catch (Exception e) {
    String m = e.getLocalizedMessage() + "; " + uri;
    log.error(m, e);
}
```

> Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
>           at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:615)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:573)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:544)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:277)
>           at com.pkgajulpalli.util.URIClient.getRawBodyForURL(URIClient.java:45)
>           ... 47 more

If I try the same URL in browser it works fine. If I restart the server, the same request works fine. Is there anything that could go wrong here with resttemplate?

Comment: First few times you get the correct response. Hence I believe the reason for Bad Request is very much because of the implementation in the Rest Service you are trying to hit. Is the number of successful hits to with the rest template constant ?

Comment: Not sure. I don't know if I can check the number of successful hits.

Comment: Is it possible to enable more extensive logs ?

Comment: This is almost for sure a server-side issue. Without information about the server-side (code, logs) it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: I've added some extra log statements in this method. Waiting for the issue to happen. As of now, the method is working fine.

Comment: After keeping some log statements and digging a little deep, I found that some of the http connections made by the RestTemplate object were not closed for a long time causing other requests fail with 400 error.